# Подменю в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragment

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане, подскажите пожалуйста в одном вопросе.
Используя support library я создал новый проект и выбрал навигацию Navigation Drawer.Все отлично и хорошо, но понадобилось в навигацию добавить подменю https://i.stack.imgur.com/awKE5.png чтобы при нажатие на пункт появлялись несколько подпунктов.
Сейчас у меня есть два стандартных файла fragment_navigation_drawer.xml и NavigationDrawerFragment.java

Пробовал использовать ExpandableListAdapter, но не удалось адекватно его вписать, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html + http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html

Comment: Видел, не получается нормально заменить стандартный компонент в fragment_navigation_drawer.xml на ExpandableListAdapter

Comment: Потому что надо ListView заменить на ExpandableListView

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался